# Laravel Intervention/image memory_limit

Tags: image, laravel, laravel-5, image-resizing, intervention

In my floder I have 120MB of images. One image - near 3 MB. I try to use this code to resize them:

```
public function images_zip(Request $request){
    if($request->width < 1 || $request->hight < 1 || $request->width > 2000 || $request->hight >2000){
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['Некорректные входные данные']);
    }
    $files = Storage::disk('images')->files('/'.$request->name.'/image');
    $mime_types = array('image/gif','image/jpeg','image/png','image/svg+xml');
    ini_set('memory_limit','128M');
    foreach ($files as $file){
        if(in_array(File::mimeType($file),$mime_types)) {
            $img = Image::make(public_path() . '/' . $file);
                $img->resize($request->width, $request->hight);
                $img->save(public_path() . '/' . $file);
                $img->destroy();
        }
    }
    return \redirect()->back();
}
```

But I take this error -

```
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)
```

I tried to use ->destroy() and ini_set('memory_limit','128M') ,like people say, but it didnt help. My server have 128MB memory. Help me,please!

Answer (score 0):

This error is probably thrown by PHP. Try to change these lines in `php.ini` file and restart the server:

```
memory_limit = 128M
```

You should also check this line:

```
max_execution_time = 30
```

This is the max execution time of a script, which can cause you problems too.

But be aware that `134217728 bytes` are exactly `128mb`. So, this should not be effective at all. If you keep the same code, you will probably need more memory.

Comment: I know that problem at code, but I cant understand where.

Comment: Try to increase the physical memory of the server, change PHP.ini, restart the server and check if the error is fixed. If the solution works, you can start working on your code.

Comment: Regarding the code, one thing you could try, is to load file by file. Try to not load all files together, since this will demand ~120mb.

Comment: I cant because its not a local server. This site stay at hosting. In my local server its work. And I checked - there 128 MB memory

Comment: How to do it? Loading file by file

Comment: A only take file names at one array, after this with foreach I resize them 1 by 1, so I dont think that its problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try editing /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini:

```
; Old Limit
; memory_limit = 512M

; New Limit
memory_limit = 2048M
```

You need to restart apache.